vue onBeforeUpdate works when route params change, but what about the first time?
My component looks like this so I can handle the first route load for a component and subsequent ones when the route param changes:
<script setup>

import {onBeforeRouteUpdate, useRoute} from "vue-router";
import {ref} from "vue";

const id = ref(useRoute().params.equipmentId)

onBeforeRouteUpdate(async (to, from) => {
  id.value = to.params.equipmentId
})

</script>

Is there a shorter, idiomatic way to do this so I don't have to handle the "one off" case of getting the initial value?

There is no official way so far, generally this requires a developer to extract common code to a function that is called in both places:
async function updateRoute(to) {...}

await updateRoute(useRoute());

onBeforeRouteUpdate(updateRoute);

There's a problem with the parity of setup and beforeRouteEnter. The lifecycle is different, no component instance exists when beforeRouteEnter runs, and no from route is available in setup. Router hooks are specific to view component, while there is no such limitation for onBeforeRouteUpdate.
This can be solved with an immediate watcher on router.currentRoute or other reactive objects if the previous route isn't in use, e.g.:
const route = useRoute();
watchEffect(() => {
  id.value = route.params.equipmentId
})

In this case the ref can be computed, since this is the intention:
const id = computed(() => route.params.equipmentId)

